# Unable to Create Resource with Powershell in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Can someone please tell me why I keep on getting the error shown in the image each time I attempt to create a NIC with Powershell in Azure?

[image: NIC]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a Network Interface, instead, you are trying to get one that does not exist. To create a NIC, use the following procedures:

```
# Get the Virtual Network 
$VNET = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name ‘Demo-vnet’ -ResourceGroupName ‘Demo’

# Get the Subnet Id
$SubnetID = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name ‘default’ -VirtualNetwork $VNET).Id

# Create the Network Interface
New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name "NICFW" -ResourceGroupName "AdatumRG" -Location "East Us" -SubnetId $SubnetID
```

Change variables accordingly and make sure -Location parameter matches your VNet location.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks mate. The solution fixed the problem. Cheers mate.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it worked for you. :)